# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have this following stored procedure in sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDocumentInfoById]
@DocumentID INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
   [DocumentID]
  ,[DocumentTitle]
  ,[DocumentVersion]

FROM 
    [dbo].[TblDocuments]
WHERE
    [DocumentID]=@DocumentID


END
```

This is my code in C#:

```
 public static DataSets.DocumentsDs GetDocumentInfoById(int documentId)
    {
        using (DbCommand loCmd = CreateDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand(GetDocumentInfoById))
        {
            using (DataSets.DocumentsDs loDocumentDs = new DataSets.DocumentsDs ())
            {

                CreateDatabase.AddInParameter(loCmd, "DocumentID", DbType.Int32, documentId);
                CreateDatabase.LoadDataSet(loCmd, loDocumentDs , loDocumentDs.DocumentDT.TableName);
                return loDocumentDs;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried this command in sql:

```
sp_help  [GetDocumentInfoById]
```

and I got this in return:

```
Name: GetDocumentInfoById
Owner: dbo
Type: stored procedure
Parameter Name: @DocumentID
```

When I run my project I get this error: Procedure or function 'GetDocumentInfoById' has too many arguments.

What am I doing wrong? Please advise. Thanks

**Update:** Using DbCommad

```
 public static DataSets.DocumentsDs GetDocumentInfoById(int documentId)
    {
        string con = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.GetValues("con").GetValue(0).ToString();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDocumentInfoById", con))
            {
                using (DataSets.DocumentsDs loDocumentDs = new DataSets.DocumentsDs ())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentID", DbType.Int32, documentId);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    CreateDatabase.LoadDataSet(loCmd, loDocumentDs , loDocumentDs.DocumentDT.TableName);
                    return loDocumentDs;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is GetStoredProcCommand setting the CommandType StoredProcedure?

Comment: @kblok no I just provided the name of the sp in there

Answer (score 4):

Parameter names should have the `@` sufix:

This should be

```
CreateDatabase.AddInParameter(loCmd, "@DocumentID", DbType.Int32, documentId);
```

Comment: still the same issue persists

Comment: Just as a test, could you rewrite that but using a DbCommand?

Comment: I just tried it again now using DbCommand and I got the same error.
I read in some other answers that it might be related to the executed sp version but as it shows the command sp_help I have just one sp has that name so I really don't know what's the issue here :/

Comment: I just posted an update usng DbCommand. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @ITDeveloper another test, could you change AddWithValue for .Parameters.Add("@DocumentID",SqlDbType.Int32).Value=documentID; ?